# a list that is the opposite probability of another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python of probabilites of something

```
aprob=[ 0.2 ,0.3, 0.0, 0.1, 0.4]
```

and I want to get a list with the probabilities of the opposite event

```
a_not_prob= [0.8, 0.7,1.0, 0.9,0.6]
```

The thing is that I am watching a tutorial and there the following works, but for me it throws an error:

```
a_not_prob=1.0-aprob
```

For me, it throws

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'
```

The funny thing is that for the instructor it works...

so How can I get the second list from the first one?

Comment: Your instructor was probably using numpy, if `aprob = np.array([ 0.2 ,0.3, 0.0, 0.1, 0.4])` then `a_not_prob = 1.0 - aprob` works

Comment: are you sure the instructor isnt using a numpy array?

Comment: If not numpy then `a_not_prob = [1.0 - a for a in aprob]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting 2 lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534855/subtracting-2-lists-in-python)

Comment: @imrakr no it does not.they are entirely different things from what i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you had reminds me of MATLAB. I haven't seen anything like that in python. But you can simply use "list comprehension" to accomplish what you're looking for. Here you are:

`a_not_prob = [ 1-x  for x in aprob]`

Comment: i wonder why people put -1 to an answer without explaning. I updated your answer

Comment: maybe cause the statement "I haven't seen anything like that in python" is false. because if it was a numpy array that is perfectly valid syntax

Comment: @DerekEden I sure could be wrong, but my statement is still True. "I" haven't seen anything in python like that yet, but by no means I claim to know everything about python and all the libraries out there. I really meant "native python" syntax like that is something I haven't seen. anyway, thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

you can't do subtraction between list and float
you can do something like that:

```
aprob=[ 0.2 ,0.3, 0.0, 0.1, 0.4]
ans = [1 - prob for prob in aprob]
print(ans)
```